# Partitions of a Number

Tags: number-theory

Given a natural number n, how do we find the recurrence for the number of distinct partitions of the number?
Note:
4 -> {4},{3,1},{2,2},{1,1,1,1},{2,1,1}
Here,
{1,3} and {3,1} are the considered the same
Also, can we get a closed form for the recurrence?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a relevant recurrence (though probably not everything you were looking for): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908701/

Answer (score 1):

The [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A000041) is a great place to look for this sort of thing.

There are explicit functions, like [Rademacher's formula](http://www3.amherst.edu/~afolsom/Folsom-Masri-MathAnn07-10.pdf) which can be truncated to give very accurate asymptotics. There are also many recurrence relations, all of which you can find an overview of on [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html).

In both cases the link will take you to the entry on the 'partition function', which is the name of what you are asking about.

Comment: There is no known explicit formula? There is Rademacher's exact formula and more, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47611/exact-formulas-for-the-partition-function).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for the link, the [Folsom-Masri](http://www3.amherst.edu/~afolsom/Folsom-Masri-MathAnn07-10.pdf) paper from that link gives a nice exposition about exact formulae.

Comment: Yes, this is a nice paper!